# CSS selector picks unexpected element

Tags: css-selectors, webdriver

I have found something interesting while trying to select an element on the following webpage:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-small-6">
        <toggle-switch params="label: $data.name">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: clicked" class="trim noUnderline New">
                <span class="toggle-off"></span>
                &nbsp;
                <span data-bind="text: label">New</span>
            </a>
        </toggle-switch>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small-6">
        <toggle-switch params="label: $data.name">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: clicked" class="trim noUnderline Placed">
                <span class="toggle-off"></span>
                &nbsp;
                <span data-bind="text: label">Placed</span>
            </a>
        </toggle-switch>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small-6">
        <toggle-switch params="label: $data.name">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: clicked" class="trim noUnderline Opened">
                <span class="toggle-off"></span>
                &nbsp;
                <span data-bind="text: label">Opened</span>
            </a>
        </toggle-switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

(The example shown is cut down a little, there are actually 12 `<div>` elements but I have only shown 3.  No idea if that makes any difference.)

For selecting the `<span>` I wanted, I was using this CSS:

`div.row div:nth-child(1) toggle-switch a span:nth-of-type(1)`

So my selector works fine.  Except when I want to select the second `<div>` element `<span>`.  My CSS is the same, I was using

`div.row div:nth-child(2) toggle-switch a span:nth-of-type(1)`

But for some reason, it was finding the first one again.  All other occurrences are working, if I want to pick the 11th one, I use `div:nth-child(11)` and it finds it no problem.

My solution was to use:

`div.row div:nth-child(2) > toggle-switch a span:nth-of-type(1)`

I have checked both CSS selectors in both Chrome and Firefox consoles using document.querySelector and they both have the same results.

My question is why does the second method work but the first method doesn't?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this problem unfortunately. Of course this example doesn't use WebDriver (which is something I'm not familiar with), but: http://jsfiddle.net/todc2rrj/.

Comment: If anyone wants to try with WebDriver, you just need to use the provided selector in FindElement, such as `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.row div:nth-child(1) toggle-switch a span:nth-of-type(1)");`

Comment: Or you can just use `document.querySelector('div.row div:nth-child(1) toggle-switch a span:nth-of-type(1)');` within the Chrome or Firefox console.